# Hiding UIImage in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

My current `UICollectionViewCell` looks like this:

[image: just a picture]

Sometimes I don't want the picture to be displayed.  When this is the case, I would like the `UICollectionViewCell` to be resized to fit tmp, tmp1, and tmp2 only.

How would I go about getting this accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set the Constraint on height of Image View in the Storyboard or in the XIB.
>   Drog the Constraint on your self UICollectionViewCell . 
>    If have an image, the Constraint.constant = your need. If have no image , the Constraint.constant = 0;

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *pictureConstraint;

@end

@implementation CollectionViewCell

- (void)setModel:(cellObject *)model{
_model = model;
self.firstLabelView.text = model.firstLabelText;
self.secondLabelView.text = model.secondLabelText;
if (model.haveImage) {
    self.pictureView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kitten"];
    self.pictureConstraint.constant = 149;
} else {
    self.pictureConstraint.constant = 0;
}}
```

in the controller set the itemSize.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
cellObject *model = self.hahaArray[indexPath.item];
CGFloat height;
if (model.haveImage) {
    height = "your pictureConstraint.constant + thirdLabel.maxY + your bottom margin  ;
} else{
    height =  thirdLabel.maxY + your bottom margin   ;
}
return  CGSizeMake(self.flowLayout.itemSize.width, height);
}
```

Comment: This works excellently and much more efficiently than having to have three or four different XIB files.  I modified it some.  Instead of implementing `setModel` and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` I put `pictureConstraint` in my header, connected it to my picture's height constraint, and modified it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.  Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is Default Collection View Delegate that help you to manage Size of CollectionViewCell.

You Can put Condition and adjust size accordingly.

```
  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 if (image)
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 500 ) ;
    return size;

}
else
{

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 200 ) ;
    return size;

}
}
```

if you are using estimated size then you can go through this example...[SelfSizingCellDemo](https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've mentioned I'm using `estimatedItemSize` for my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and can't use `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.  I would like to stick with `estimatedItemSize` if humanly possible as my `UILabel`s are variable length depending on user content.

Comment: you are using storyboard  ..?

Comment: is it feasible for you to have two CollectionViewCell and with different identifier. One cell with Image and other without Image then it make simple for you and if you are using estimated Item Size then.then get the estimated item size and store that in constant and pass that constant value in that delegate.